# Linq mapping EntityDb to Dto is very slow, one record

Tags: performance, entity-framework, linq, dto

Linq mapping EntityDb to Dto is very slow.

I get the only ONE record from table with join other tables by Id.

Example:

```
DataAccess da;

var res = from t1 in da.Table1
          join t2 in da.Table2 on t1.rf_table2Id equals t2.Table2Id
          join etc...
          over 20 joins...

          where t1.Table1Id == 20 /*example*/
          select new MyDto
          {
            Id = t1.Table1Id,
            Name = t1.Name,
            Type = new ReferenceDto() 
            {
                Id = t2.Table2Id,
                Name = t2.Name
            },

            and etc...
            over 50 fields
          };
```

The problem in mapping. If I get the record without mapping all fields, only Id,
`res.FirstOrDefault()` executes in 100-500 milliseconds, fast.

But, if I map all fields the `res.FirstOrDefault()` takes 3 seconds to execute, which is too slow.

My DTO is structure view.

In SQL Server Profiler, the query runs very fast.

What can I do ?

I need to get more information at the one time, by Id the record.

Comment: *only Id* -- what do you mean by that? I'm pretty sure that this is a query in which EF ignores most, or even all, joins. Look at the generated SQL for both queries. Also, "over 20 joins" spells trouble anyway. It probably means EF has to do a lot of post-processing to create an object graph from the flat result set coming form the database.

Comment: I get the record by Id. In SQL Server Profiler I get the sql-query, which runs fast, who return ONE record by Id with all data from 20 tables (in join to each other). I'm not stupid.

Comment: Please show the LINQ query that returns in 500 ms. Mapping cannot possibly add 2.5 seconds to a 500ms query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is:**

1) I get the original sql-query from SQL Server Profiler.

2) Create plain DTO class (over 200 fields) for execute query by context.ExecuteStoreQuery.

3) Then, I've done mapping the result plain DTO to my structure DTO Model.

**Conclusion is:**

About 3 seconds to execute linq statement with mapping to big structure DTO with about 200 fields.

And ONLY 500-600 milliseconds with new solution, described above!!!

Improved by 5-6 times!!!

With large DTO structure linq statement is bad, when we want to get the large record data (with many tables) by Id.

P.S.
Structure DTO Model is class with sub-classes, example:

```
 select new MyDto
          {
             Id = t1.Table1Id,
             Name = t1.Name,
             Type = new ReferenceDto() 
             {
                Id = t2.Table2Id,
                Name = t2.Name
             },

             and etc...
             over 50 fields
          };
```